# These packages need to be imported from (in the NAMESPACE file)

Tags: r, package

In trying to create a local R package, I listed some dependent packages as Depends:

```
...
Description: NA
License: GPL-2
Depends:R (>= 2.15.0),
    survival,
    PropCIs,
    boot,
    msm,
    reshape2
LazyData: true
```

But I got these message by run R CMD check:

```
 *checking dependencies in R code ... NOTE
Packages in Depends field not imported from:
  ‘PropCIs’ ‘boot’ ‘msm’ ‘reshape2’ ‘survival’
  These packages need to be imported from (in the NAMESPACE file)
  for when this namespace is loaded but not attached.
```

Then I use manually added these packages to NAMESPACE file, but it does work and the import lines were deleted automatically after checking.

Another weird thing is the checking process showed:

```
R CMD check succeeded
```

But the files then disappeared or deleted systematically/automatically.

May somebody know the reasons?

Comment: are you using roxygen2/devtools (perhaps via RStudio) to develop?  The NAMESPACE file will be generated automatically, so you need to make sure you have the right @imports directives in your roxygen code ...

Comment: As a side question - do you really need all of those in Depends instead of in Imports?

Comment: A little googling turns up a detailed explanation: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-October/361984.html. Giving [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Package-Dependencies) a read might help clear up imports/depends for you, too.

Comment: Thank you all. Yes, I use roxygen2 and devtools via RStudio. But it seems no problem if I check the package from terminal rather through RStudio. I'd guess RStudio might have a little bug.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just add the following lines to your roxygen code:

```
@import PropCIs boot msm reshape2 survival
```

Comment: Where should that tag go?

Comment: I put it in the roxygen code associated with the calling function's documentation.

Comment: I put in the package documentation
```
#' Oak
#'
#' Automate SDTMv Mapping, Specifications Generation
#'
#' @docType package
#' @name oak
#' @noRd
#' @import rgdsr
#'
NULL
```